# Material UI Menu not closing after clicking a menu item

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, dialog, material-ui

This is code straight from MUI menu - customized menu.. I didn't want to put my code because there are some built in functions that make it more confusing.

In my code (not this) I open a MUI Dialog when a menu item is clicked. The issue is that the menu does not go away after the Dialog is submitted.

I would like to know how to make the menu close as soon as anything on the menu is clicked(menu items).

Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu, { MenuProps } from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import DraftsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Drafts';
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';

const StyledMenu = withStyles({
  paper: {
    border: '1px solid #d3d4d5',
  },
})((props: MenuProps) => (
  <Menu
    elevation={0}
    getContentAnchorEl={null}
    anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: 'bottom',
      horizontal: 'center',
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
      vertical: 'top',
      horizontal: 'center',
    }}
    {...props}
  />
));

const StyledMenuItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '&:focus': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      '& .MuiListItemIcon-root, & .MuiListItemText-primary': {
        color: theme.palette.common.white,
      },
    },
  },
}))(MenuItem);

export default function CustomizedMenus() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        aria-controls="customized-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <StyledMenu
        id="customized-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <StyledMenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <SendIcon fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Sent mail" />
        </StyledMenuItem>
        <StyledMenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DraftsIcon fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
        </StyledMenuItem>
        <StyledMenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InboxIcon fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        </StyledMenuItem>
      </StyledMenu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What does ```keepMounted``` use for?

Answer (score 21):

You can just assign `handleClose` handler to the `onClick` property of the `<Menu>` itself like this:

```
<StyledMenu
  onClick={handleClose}
  onClose={handleClose}
  {...yourProps}
>
 ...
</StyledMenu>
```

Comment: That did the trick, it feels strange but it works!!

Answer (score 9):

You can put an onClick prop to the `MenuItem`:

```
<StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Text</StyledMenuItem>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issues over a year after you wrote it!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue, couldn't apply [hangindev.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9912194/hangindev-com) solution to my problem. Only difference was that my menu items were `children` passed outside of the menu component.
You could use the `onBlur` event on `StyledMenu`.

```js
<StyledMenu
    id="customized-menu"
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    keepMounted
    open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
    onClose={handleClose}
    onBlur={handleClose}
  >{children}<StyledMenu>
```

Sorry for posting after 2 years, I hope this contributes. I used **@mui/material 5.4.0** version.

Comment: Thanks, keepMounted was crucial for me since I was passing a Dialog a a child to the Menu.

Answer (score 1):

onBlur={handleClose} works correctly if pass  comp as children for other

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and the top voted answer wasn't working for me. Instead of fighting Material UI, I kept it simple and this is working great:

```js
{anchorElUser ? (
  <Menu
    anchorEl={anchorElUser}
    open={true}
    onClose={handleClose}
    onClick={handleClose}
  >
    {menuItems.map(...)}
  </Menu>
) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

we may use `onClick` instead of `onClose` in

```
   <StyledMenu
        id="customized-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClick={onClose}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same issue in MUI menu

So as a solution I disabled the portal and unsetted the zIndex to MUI Menu component.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khGkp.png)

```
<Menu
  sx={{
    zIndex: { xs: 1300, md: 'unset' },
  }}
  disablePortal
>
  // Lists  
</Menu>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).